# vue router – add class #1 when leaving view + add class #2 after dom update

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to implement a transition between each individual views by adding a class to the `router-view` parent `div` when leaving the current view and after appending the new view.

I can't use the `<transition>` tag because there's a necessary `:key` on the `<router-view>` tag which breaks the transition tag in Vue 3.

I tried the vue router Navigation Guards but it seems to missing an "after dom update" hook. (?)

```
const routes = [
  path: '/foo',
  component: 'bar,
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    document.querySelector('main').classList.add('animated')
    console.log("beforeenter")
    setTimeout(() => {
      next()
    }, 1000)
  }
]
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: you can also add <transition> in components as root element

Comment: Hi, i tried that, however the transition is not triggered. Probably also because of the :key, which I need.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the watch hook on the $route combined with the beforeEnter navigation guard inside the router.